# Differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Show that the differential equation $$\frac{dy}{dx} =\frac{e^x+x}{\sin y+2}$$ has a solution satisfying $y(0) = \pi$. To do this, separate variables and integrate to get an equation implicitly relating $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 3):

$$
\frac {dy}{dx} = \frac {e^x + x}{\sin y + 2} \\
(\sin y + 2) dy = (e^x + x) dx \\
\int (\sin y + 2) dy = \int (e^x + x) dx \\
-\cos y + 2y = e^x + \frac {x^2}2 + C
$$
Now, substitute $y(0) = \pi$
$$
1 + 2\pi = 1 + C
$$
from which you can find that $C = 2\pi$.

Final answer is
$$
2y - \cos y = e^x + \frac {x^2}2 + 2\pi
$$
is a solution of a given ODE and satisfies $y(0) = \pi$.

Comment: Why is there a C? Isn't after integral both side, and there are two C at the left and right, then the C will be cancelled out? And how you get e^x+x^2/2 = 1?

Comment: @Karen You get $C_1$ on one side and $C_2$ on the other and the difference is $C$ - the two constants cannot be assumed to be the same.

Comment: oh right! my mistake!

Comment: then where did your other C go?

Comment: @Karen $C$ was determined based on your initial condition $y(0) = \pi$. It's all written in the post.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a start. You need to use the [existence and uniqueness theorem](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~tyson/existence.pdf#page=2&zoom=121,0,777) for first order ode.

$$ \frac{dy}{dx} =\frac{e^x+x}{\sin y+2}=F(x,y).$$

Now, just find $F_y=\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}$ and apply the theorem.